# Implementing aggregator pattern for AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to implement an aggregating lambda `A`, which asynchronously calls lambdas `B`, `C`, `D` and then gets their results on completion, or errors on failure. I also wouldn't use `Process`+`Pipe` parallelism.

How can I do that?

Maybe custom waiters? But I'm not sure how can I implement one for lambda `on success`/`on error` events.

Comment: "gets their results on completion" from where? Do these lambdas store the results in SQS, S3, ...?

Comment: @Marcin Any result storage works for me. I don't understand how can I know if my async invocation is complete, and how can I get the result of this specific invocation in the aggregator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is `AWS Step Functions`, check [example use cases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html#application) to figure out how to orchestrate lambdas (and other services) execution. Particularly you will be interested in the callback pattern https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-example